# Chamar Form2 com Circular Progress Bar enquanto outra ação é executada C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a chamada de um Windows Form.
Nessa aplicação, através do evento do clique do botão localizado no Form1, chamar um segundo Form, onde nesse form2 apresento um Circular Progress Bar animado rodando até que um outro método localizado no Form 1  chamado CarregarGrid() seja finalizado.

Nesse Momento minha aplicação encontra-se com o seguinte código:

Evento do Botão localizado no Form 1:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public partial class frm_Painel_de_Producao : Form
{
 frm_Progress_Bar pb = frm_Progress_Bar();

    private async void btnAtualizaGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      pb.Show();

      //desabilita os botões enquanto a tarefa é executada.
      btnCancelar.Enabled = false;
      btnIncluir.Enabled = false;      
      btnAtualizaGrid.Enabled = false;

      // simply start and await the loading task
      await Task.Run(() => carregarGrid());
      pb.Close();

      // habilita os botões após  tarefa evento de loading.
      btnAtualizaGrid.Enabled = true;
      btnCancelar.Enabled = true;
      btnIncluir.Enabled = true;    

    }

 }
```

Código do Form 2 somente Initialize:

```
public partial class frm_Progress_Bar : Form
{
    public frm_Progress_Bar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }  
}
```

Designer do Form 2 + Progress Bar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Propriedade do Form 2:
**Back Color**  = Fuchsia
**Transparency Key** = Fuchsia

Propriedade do Circular Progress Bar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse Caso nas propriedades já se encontra com Style: Marquee Pois Li em algum lugar que essa propriedade deve estar como Marquee, *"se não me engano para poder continuar dar o efeito de loading."*

Método do Form 1 CarregarGrid:

```
public void carregarGrid()
    {

        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += meuRelogio;
        timer.Start();
        dgvProducao.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvProducao.DataSource = clsPPCP.painelProducao();
        MeuBD.AbreXML();
        if (MeuBD.RequerUsuario == "1")
        {
            txtOperador.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            txtOperador.Hide();
            txtNomeOperador.Hide();
            label8.Hide();
            txtCartao.Focus();
        }
        colorirGrid();
        //MeuBDex.AbreXML();
        relogio();   
    }
```

Com essas informações agora reporto os erros que encontrei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse erro está acontecendo pois no evento do clique  estou colocando o seguinte código:  `await Task.Run(() => carregarGrid());`

Com isso ocorre o lendário erro: *Operação entre threads inválida: controle '' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.*

tentei refazer essa aplicação então utilizando Thread e Delegates mas também não obtive exito  por por falta  experiência com Threads.

E mais uma vez refiz essa aplicação tentando apontar no Evento de Load do Form2,
chamar o método carregarGrid do Form1. Respeitando a criação de instancia do Form 1 dentro Form2. Porém também não obtive exito.

Então pessoal venho humildemente pedir a vocês como posso resolver essa aplicação? 
Dúvidas:

1- Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com Circular Progress Bar?

2- Utilizo O ProgressBar em outro Form como no exemplo acima?
Ou Consigo colocar o Progress Bar no mesmo Form1.

3- Também seria possível no Evento de Load do Form 1 estar chamando o método CarregarGrid e assim que o método for finalizado, a ProgressBar com o Form2 seja encerrado?

Já deixo meus agradecimentos por toda a ajuda. **Obrigado!**

Comment: Resolveu jovem ?

Comment: Bom dia,muito obrigado pelas dicas mas ainda não Rovann, não entendi muito bem o exemplo. Sou inciante na programação então até peço desculpas se não for muito claro para mim.

Comment: Bom dia, fale sua dúvida que tentamos ajudar.

Comment: Como posso fazer para entrar um 2form  ou no próprio form 1  o plugin Circular progress bar enquanto eu carrego o Grid através do clique do botão atualizar grid. esse circular progress bar não vai carregar por exemplo de 0 a 100%  e sim ficar rodando somente até terminar a aplicação do grid.  Não sei se fui muito claro na minha dúvida?

Comment: sim, está implementando meu exemplo com o backgroundworker ?

Comment: Estou tentando implementa-lo. O backgroundWorker1 é um  evento do form 2?

Comment: não... esquece o form2... não tem no meu exemplo... o backgroundWorker1 é um controle que você insere no form1 pela toolbox

Comment: Alterei minha resposta... veja lá

Comment: Obrigado Rovann estou entendendo um pouco agora, estou com sua resposta e o site do macoratti aberto aqui falando sobre o backgroundworker.

Comment: Assim que conseguir  ou tiver outra dúvida eu posto aqui, primeiro vou entender sobre o backgroundworker e tentar aplicar sua resposta na aplicação. Mais uma vez Obrigado!

Comment: certo, não se esqueça de marcar como resposta se te ajudou

Comment: Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias formas de fazer a barra de progresso, mas acredito que se tratando de `Windows Forms`, o ideal seja utilizar o `BackgroundWorker` que realiza o trabalho em segundo plano, deixando a Thread do form livre pra mostrar o progresso na barra.

Fiz um Exemplo de como ele funciona:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) //se o bw não estiver ocupado...
    {
        int arg = 100000;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(arg); //você pode passar um argumento pro bw
    }
}


private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //iniciou o processo em segundo plano
    int total = (int)e.Argument;
    int valor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++)
    {
        valor += i;

        int p = i * 100 / total; //calcula percentual do progresso

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(p); //informa o percentual do progresso
    }

    e.Result = valor;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; //exibe o percentual na barra
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //evento quando o processo é finalizado
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //processo foi cancelado
        //tem que definir o bw pra suportar cancelamento e verificar a flag e.Cancel dentro do processo...
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        //deu erro e foi lançada exceção
    }
    else
    {
        int resultado = (int)e.Result;
        MessageBox.Show("Resultado: "+ resultado);
    }
}
```

> O exemplo acima, responde às questões 1 e 2. A 3, basta disparar o bw depois que abrir o form. Fechar o outro form com a progressBar já não é preciso...

Para inserir o `BackGroundWorker` basta arrastá-lo da toolbar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois colocar os eventos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não solucionei por completo mas com sua resposta consegui abrir um norte   com  esses eventos background work.