# C# - DataGridView não altera propriedade DefaultCellStyle.BackColor enviado de uma classe para o Form

Tags: c#, .net

Estou com uma dúvida em C# em respeito a DataGridView.

Nesse cenário tenho um Form onde executo um Datagrid trazendo informações de outra classe.
Depois que os dados são carregados pelo Datagrid.Datasource o Grid é exibido na tela sem problemas.
**Dúvida:**
Depois desta tarefa preciso que as Rows do data grid sejam coloridas conforme a logica da minha aplicação.
Nesse caso eu crio uma classe chamada AcoesGrid onde ela vai ser responsável " como já diz o nome" por fazer qualquer tipo de ação no Grid.
Nessa classe está o código onde as rows devem ser coloridas.
Para isso criei uma propriedade do Data grid na classe Acoes grid:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Onde atribuo o Data grid do Formulário.
No Formulário chamado Visualizar Grid faço a referencia entre a propriedade e o data grid:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Depois de Trabalhar no Grid  eu retorno a propriedade da classe para o formulário, **"mas ao mostrar o Formulário com o Grid na tela ela continua com as informações do DataSource  mas  sem estar colorindo o grid."**
Segue o código da classe para melhor entendimento:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ppcp_protheus.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using ppcp_protheus.Acesso_a_Dados;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;

namespace ppcp_protheus
{
   class clsAcoesGrid
   {
        //Propriedade criada para receber o Objeto Data Grid  do formulario Visualizar Grid.
    public DataGridView RefObjDgvPrincipal { get; set; }

    List<clsPbx> listPbx = new List<clsPbx>();

    DateTime dataBanco;
    string email;

    #region Métodos

    public  DataGridView colorirGrid(clsConexao dbCon)//, DataGridView dgvPrincipal)
    {

        //-------conectaBD.AbreXML();
        List<clsProducao> listOpsAprov = new List<clsProducao>();

        for (int i = 0; i < RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string operacao = RefObjDgvPrincipal[2, i].Value.ToString();
            DateTime previsao = Convert.ToDateTime(RefObjDgvPrincipal[7, i].Value.ToString() + " " + RefObjDgvPrincipal[8, i].Value.ToString());
            //DateTime previsao = Convert.ToDateTime("05/06/2018 01:52:00");
            string ordem = RefObjDgvPrincipal[10, i].Value.ToString();

            OdbcDataReader dr;
            string id = "";
            string ctde = "";
            string ctpara = "";
            string _sqlemail = "";
            string _notificado = "";

            foreach (clsPbx item in listPbx)
            {
                if (item._pbxCte == ordem)
                {
                    id = item._pbxId;
                    ctde = item._pbxCte;
                    ctpara = item._pbxCtpara;
                }
            }


            if (operacao.Contains("P"))
            {
                RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (ordem.Substring(0, 2).Equals("AP"))
            {
                RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (previsao <= dataBanco)
            {
                RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                if (dbCon.VerificaStatusConexao() == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    dbCon.Conectar();

                _sqlemail = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM producao_SAP_V8 WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ordemproducao = '" + ordem + "'";
                dr = dbCon.RetornaDataReader(_sqlemail);

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    _notificado = dr["notificado"].ToString();
                }


                dr.Dispose();
                dr.Close();

                if (_notificado != "1")
                {
                    clsEnviarEmail enviarEmail = new clsEnviarEmail();
                    enviarEmail.EnviaEmail(email, "Apontamento de Produção", "A Ordem de Produção," + ordem + ",ultrapassou o tempo padrão ", "");


                    try
                    {
                        if (dbCon.VerificaStatusConexao() == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            dbCon.Conectar();
                        OdbcTransaction tran = dbCon.Connection.BeginTransaction();
                        string _exclui = String.Format("UPDATE producao_SAP_V8 Set notificado = '1' WHERE ordemproducao = '{0}'", ordem);
                        OdbcCommand odbcCMD = new OdbcCommand(_exclui, dbCon.Connection);
                        odbcCMD.Transaction = tran;
                        //odbcCMD.Parameters.Add("codigomotivo",OdbcType.VarChar,10).Value = motivo;

                        if (odbcCMD.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
                        {
                            tran.Commit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tran.Rollback();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        dbCon.FechaBanco();
                    }
                }

                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();


            }
            else
            {
                RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            }

            if (ctde != "" && id != "")
            {
                if (ctpara.Equals("Gray"))
                {
                    RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                }
                else if (ctpara.Equals("White"))
                {
                    RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else if (ctpara.Equals("Orange"))
                {
                    RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                }
                else if (ctpara.Equals("Purple"))
                {
                    RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                }
                else if (ctpara.Equals("Brown"))
                {
                    RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown;
                }
            }

            if (dbCon.Depto.Equals("03") && !operacao.Contains("P"))
            {
                string sqlAprov = String.Format(@"SELECT PC1.PC1_NUMOP AS ORDEM from PC1100 PC1 WITH(NOLOCK) where PC1.PC1_COD = '{0}'", ordem);
                dr = dbCon.RetornaDataReader(sqlAprov);

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    clsProducao prod = new clsProducao();
                    prod.OrdemProducao = dr["ORDEM"].ToString();
                    listOpsAprov.Add(prod);
                }
                dr.Dispose();
                dr.Close();

                foreach (clsProducao item in listOpsAprov)
                {
                    if (item.OrdemProducao == ordem)
                    {
                        RefObjDgvPrincipal.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return RefObjDgvPrincipal;
    }
    #endregion
  }
 }
```

Segue o código do Formulário:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ppcp_protheus.Forms;

namespace ppcp_protheus.Forms
{
   public partial class frm_Visualizar_Grid : Form
   {
     clsConexao conectaBD = new clsConexao();

    string setor;

    public frm_Visualizar_Grid()//string depto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //setor = depto;
    }

    private void frm_Visualizar_Grid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Funcao do CarregarGrid
        conectaBD.AbreXML(setor);


        dgvUsinagem.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvUsinagem.DataSource = clsPPCP.painelProducao(conectaBD);

        clsAcoesGrid acoesGrid = new clsAcoesGrid();

        //Enviando Objeto dgvUsinagem para Propriedade criada na classe clsAcoesGrid
        acoesGrid.RefObjDgvPrincipal = this.dgvUsinagem;
        //clsAcoesGrid.RefObjDgvPrincipal = this.dgvUsinagem;
        acoesGrid.colorirGrid(conectaBD);
        dgvUsinagem = acoesGrid.colorirGrid(conectaBD);//, dgvUsinagem);
        //dgvUsinagem = clsAcoesGrid.colorirGrid(conectaBD);//, dgvUsinagem);
        //dgvUsinagem.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = acoesGrid.RefObjDgvPrincipal.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

        //dgvUsinagem.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

    }
    public void CarregaDepto(string depto)
    {
        setor = depto;
    }
  }
 }
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado se alguem puder ajudar...
Já deixo meus agradecimento pela ajuda.
Obrigado.

Comment: aparentemente você criou um método que retorna um outro DataGridView, chama o método mas não aplica o retorno em lugar nenhum. Além disso o código está bem confuso...

Comment: a proposito, você tem outra pergunta que não foi resolvida ou vc não marcou como resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307928/chamar-form2-com-circular-progress-bar-enquanto-outra-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-executada-c

Comment: Desculpe pensei que eu já tinha selecionado com resposta a pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307928/chamar-form2-com-circular-progress-bar-enquanto-outra-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-executada-c

Comment: o return desse metodo:   public  DataGridView colorirGrid(clsConexao dbCon)
    { }  return RefObjDgvPrincipal;       "Não era para retornar o datagrid para o formulário? código do form: dgvUsinagem = acoesGrid.colorirGrid(conectaBD);?

Comment: se está retornando, ele deveria ser atribuido, algo como `dgvUsinagem = acoesGrid.colorirGrid(conectaBD);` mas não faz sentido fazer isso... tente separar melhor o que cada método faz... e retornar a lógica das cores já no select dos dados

Comment: Como ? pode me dar um exemplo? retornar as cores da propriedade tipo datagril para outro Datagrid?

Comment: o que é `clsProducao` e `clsPbx` ? Qual a lógica pra aplicação das cores ?

Comment: A logica para aplicação das cores  esta no  nos if / else   por exemplo  a operação conter  substring "P"  quer dizer que na minha base estra trazendo uma operação de Parada de equipamento.

Comment: Então a linha vai ser colorida por uma cor.  Se a previsão de fabricação da peça exceder a data banco preenche a linha com outra cor   e por ai vai, tem vários  no bloco de códio.  clsProdução  traz uma lista de Ops= ordem de produção com aproveitamento de apontamentos.  Me tire oura dúvida esta  certo eu fazer a propriedade do tipo data grid  e nela enviar o datagrid para outra classe  e depois retornar do jeito que fiz  ou não existe  aplicações melhores?

Comment: veja se a resposta ajuda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como falei nos comentários não dá pra saber muito bem como está seu programa, por isso montei um exemplo para colorir as linhas do DataGridView.

A lógica que será usada pra definir as cores, você pode colocar na classe, os dados para utiliza-la já devem vir no select, e não executar o select dentro de um loop. Isso irá prejudicar terrivelmente o desempenho.

Para o exemplo, criei a classe Item, que representa cada item ou linha do DataGridView:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor => Ativo ? (Valor > 0 ? Color.Green : Color.Blue ) : Color.Red;
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

Repare que aqui já é feita a condição para a cor: Se Ativo verifica o valor, se for maior que zero, a cor é verde; se for menor, azul; Se inativo, vermelho.

Para simular um Select no banco de dados, fiz um método estático que retorna uma lista de itens:

```
public static class SimulaDb
{
    public static List<Item> GetItens()
    {
        List<Item> itens = new List<Item>();
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, Descricao = "Item 1", Ativo = true, Valor = 0 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 2, Descricao = "Item 2", Ativo = true, Valor = 10 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 3, Descricao = "Item 3", Ativo = true, Valor = 4 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 4, Descricao = "Item 4", Ativo = false, Valor = -10 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 5, Descricao = "Item 5", Ativo = true, Valor = -5 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 6, Descricao = "Item 6", Ativo = true, Valor = 1 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 7, Descricao = "Item 7", Ativo = false, Valor = 70 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 8, Descricao = "Item 8", Ativo = true, Valor = 50 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 9, Descricao = "Item 9", Ativo = false, Valor = 80 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 10, Descricao = "Item 10", Ativo = true, Valor = 14 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 11, Descricao = "Item 11", Ativo = true, Valor = 12 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 12, Descricao = "Item 12", Ativo = true, Valor = -1 });
        itens.Add(new Item() { Id = 13, Descricao = "Item 13", Ativo = true, Valor = 150 });


        return itens;
    }
}
```

Pronto. Agora o código do Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Item> _itens;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _itens = SimulaDb.GetItens();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _itens;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = _itens[r.Index].BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

No Evento Load, recebo os dados do "Banco de Dados" e armazeno na lista.

Manipulei o evento `DataBindingComplete`, para que, ao carregar os dados, percorremos cada `DataGridViewRow` do `DataGridView` e aplicamos a cor na linha.

> Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Optei pelo evento `DataBindingComplete` pois este só ocorre uma vez ao atribuir os dados ao controle. Outro eventos ficam sendo disparados a todo momento.

Comment: Utilizando  o evento DataBindingComplete  como exemplo que o nosso amigo Rovann propôs. Consegui resolver o problema. Deixo aqui o código que utilizei e meus agradecimentos por toda  ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Evento DataBidingComplete usado  quando o conteúdo dos dados de origem  forem  alterados, 
    //no caso preciso verificar as linhas "Rows" do DataGridview onde a propriedade BackColor foi alterada.
    private void dgvPrincipal_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        acoesGrid.CarregaDp(conectaBD);
        acoesGrid.colorirGrid(dgvPrincipal);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvPrincipal.Rows)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = acoesGrid.listItens[r.Index].BackColor;
        }
    }
```